# How to fix Plotly Heatmap block size?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

Here is my HeatMap plot function :

```py
def plot_heatmap(alphas, k_list, title_prefix="", years=["Y2013", "Y2014"]):
    data = [
        Heatmap(
            name="",
            z= alphas,
            x=years,
            y=k_list,
            hoverongaps = False,
            zauto=False,
            zmin=zmin,
            zmax=zmax,
            colorscale= color_custom,
            colorbar = dict(
                title="Alpha Value",
                thicknessmode="pixels",
                thickness=50,
                yanchor="top",
                y=1,
                len=480,
                lenmode="pixels",
                ticks="outside",
                dtick=zmax / 10
                )
        )
    ]
    fig = Figure(
        data=data,
        layout=Layout(
            width = 640,
            height = round(60 * len(k_list)) if round(60 * len(k_list)) > 640 else 640,
            # autosize = True,
            title=title_prefix + " | HeatMap : alphas",
        )
    )
    fig.data[0]['hoverinfo'] = 'all'
    fig['layout']['yaxis']['scaleanchor']='x'
    iplot(fig)
```

Right now my work around is `height = round(60 * len(k_list)) if round(60 * len(k_list)) > 640 else 640,`  in the `*Layout` object.

Result is like this : (**I don't want to see the grey parts on the plot, how can I do that**)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that for some reason plotly takes your `years` input to be numerical, you can make this variable explicitly categorical by adding

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['type'] = 'category'
```

Comment: It helps a lot for my big heatmaps over 100 rows it maintains a good looking block width and height. But I still have some grey zone on the left and right of my heatmap... It might not be handle properly by plotly ?

Comment: when you have `None` values plotly does not display them, as you can see in the picture you posted on the `K10017` row, if this is not the case make sure the size of `years` matches the corresponding dimension of `alphas`, I think that should do. You can also change the background color using `fig['layout']['plot_bgcolor'] = 'white'` if nothing works.

Comment: Indeed None values have the color of the background. `years` and `alphas` have exactly the same length. `fig['layout']['plot_bgcolor'] = 'white'`make the plot prettier thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem while setting fixed aspect ratio to figure.

Found the answer here
https://plotly.com/python/axes/#fixed-ratio-axes-with-compressed-domain

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['constrain'] = 'domain'
```

Answer (score 1):

do this :

**fig.update_xaxes(tickson='boundaries') 

fig.update_yaxes(tickson='boundaries')**